# ASP.Net: Render linked javascript files on page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, render

I'm using a CSS StyleManager that let's me combine & render all my CSS files into one string ON THE PAGE. So I have no more external CSS files.

I wanna do the same thing with my javascript libraries. Is there a smart way how to achieve this without reading the files within page_load and adding the text to the page myself?

Background info: I wanna save the website as one single file for a distribution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For performance you should use external (css & javascript files) so that they can be cached by the browser & your page will load faster.
Also, to reduce http requests you can combine your external css & javascript file in one using [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of the performance aspect. However I know exactly that I have little JS in this case and it would be no problem to add them all as one string.

Comment: I want to achieve the effect of having to distribute as little as possible files (in the best case 1).